# PostgreSQL how to improve running time of an update query that uses date_part

Tags: sql, postgresql-10

I ran the following query so as to calculate how many days have passed since the `actiondate` in a new table field that I have previously defined (`days_from_action`):

```
update email_table 
set days_from_action = ((date_part('year', now())-date_part('year', actiondate))*365)
                      + (date_part('month', now())-date_part('month', actiondate))*30
                      + (date_part('day', now())-date_part('day', actiondate));
```

The `email_table` table has 1.8 billion rows and the query took 22 hours to be executed. Does this time makes sense? Could I somehow write another faster query for this?

Comment: Are you planning on doing this update multiple times? Why not make it a computed/calculated field instead?

Comment: Bad idea to store calculated values that will be out of date tomorrow...

Comment: Why are you storing that information to begin with? Calculating that value while retrieving is quite cheap, updating 1.8 billion rows **will** take a lot of time. As you are updating all rows, there is no way to make this faster. The expression itself can be simplified though: `current_date - actiondate::date`  (if actiondate is already a `date` then you don't even need the `::date` cast)

Comment: your update changes every row in the table, so it's not a big surprise that it takes its time

Comment: `date_part()` has pretty much nothing to do with the timing issue.  Updating 1.8 billion rows has everything to do with the performance.  You should be computing this value when you retrieve the data, in a view.  After all `now()` is significantly different when the query is done compared to when it began.